# Multiple values from one loop php

Tags: php, arrays

If I have this array -

```
$data_item['actor_id'] = $this->input->post('actor_id');
$data_item['item_number'] = $this->input->post('item_number');
```

Which gives me this array -

```
Array ( 
    [actor_id] => Array ( 
        [0] => 162652153 
        [1] => 162652154 
    ) 
    [item_number] => Array ( 
        [0] => 3 
        [1] => 6 
    ) 
)
```

I need to get my data into this format -

```
$data = array(
   array(
      'actor_id' => '3342' ,
      'item_number' => '57567'
   ),
   array(
      'actor_id' => '876' ,
      'item_number' => '94' 
   )
);
```

I have tried various ways of looping through it but I can't seem to get it. Such as two seperate loops like this -

```
foreach($data_item['actor_id'] as $key => $value){
$thevalue[] = array('actor_id' => $value
                            );
}
```

But it is wrong format. Any tips please?

Comment: None of those numbers seems to match anything, so what exactly do you want to do here ?

Comment: are the size of $data_item['actor_id'] and $data_item['item_number'] is always equal ?

Comment: The data in the arrays is just an example. Basically, I need to turn take the first array and change it into the same format as the 2nd array. And like in the second one, I need to add those key names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
$d = [
    'actor_id' => [
        1,
        2,
    ],
    'item_number' => [
        3,
        4,
    ],
]; 

$res = [];
foreach ( $d as $key => $data ) {
    foreach ( $data as $index => $value ) {
        $res [ $index ] [$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

I'll generate:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["actor_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["item_number"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["actor_id"]=>
    int(2)
    ["item_number"]=>
    int(4)
  }
}
```

HTH

Comment: Actually, meant to comment on this one and upvote it. ...not sure about the other one, this is what I used.

Comment: @sean: actually pretty much the same, only that the other solution does more error checking in case unexpected parameters come... in your case you might want to stick without error checking

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of the actor_id keys to flatten your data as desired:

```
$data = array();  // your new array
foreach($data_item['actor_id'] as $key => $value) {
    // make sure we have an array for this key and add actor id
    if (!isset($data[$key])) $data[$key] = array();
    $data[$key]['actor_id'] = $value;
    // now check if we have an item number for this key and add it
    if (isset($data_item['item_number'][$key]))
        $data[$key]['item_number'] = $data_item['item_number'][$key];
}
print_r($data);
```

The result should print out just as you wanted it. Sorry for not having tested the code my self, just typed it out of my head missing time and interpreter right now :)

Comment: Nice. That did it. I just had to change my post items at the top of the page to two different variable names and then do $data_item = array_merge($data_itemone, $data_itemtwo); ...then used $data_item with your code. Thanks.